# Javascript Broken - Syntax highlighting not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

When I go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200088/bootstrap-column-reordering-sizing-problems/30200685#30200685), the syntax highlighting doesn't render properly.

The console gives the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>   [full-anon.en.js?v=dfc750b803ca](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=dfc750b803ca)

[image: error screenshot]

I'm in Incognito, so I have no extensions enabled
I'm on Win 8.1 in Chrome 42.0.2311.135 m

Comment: This isn't limited to one question.  Its on every question I've visited so far.  I came here to report it, but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: @Daedalus, that's probably true, but I wanted to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: In fact, the toolbar at the top is broken for me on SO.

Comment: Yeah, all JS is broken right at the moment - please stand by...

Comment: Ok, should be good now. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: No inconvenience at all.  @Shog9, you da man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.  It was my mistake.

We're doing a little bit of investigation around how people browse questions (mostly around how they move between lists and actual questions) and I introduced a defect that bombed out the rest of the JS on the question/show page if you *weren't* coming from a list.